# Integrity Contraint Violation: Magento

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento

We are having the following error on our Magento 1.6 site.

Stack trace:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`magento`.`salesrule_product_attribute`,
>   CONSTRAINT `FK_81C9080E12F14369F8C7AF39A88AEF48` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`customer_group_id`) REFERENCES `customer_group` (`custome)' in
>   /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

I'm a frontend developer so any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The fault turned out to be caused by deleting a customer group which had a shopping cart price rule associated with it.

It was easily fixed by recreating the deleted customer group and then going to the shopping cart price rule and re-saving without the customer group you want to remove. You can then go ahead and delete the customer group again.